# Spring Rest controller returns 404 not found for POST method invocation

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting a  404 NOT found for my Spring boot rest controller invocation

Following is my rest controller class:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/v2")
    public class PassengerController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/addPassengerDetails", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public Passenger addPassenger(@RequestBody Passenger p) {
            System.out.println("in Passenger Controller");
            // logic to return Passenger Type response
        }
```

I am seeing the following logs and the SYSO statement itself does not get printed.

```
    o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/v2/addPassengerDetails", parameters={}
     DEBUG 1252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
   DEBUG 1252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
    --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
    --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
```

Here is my Request Body for the POST invocation:

{
    "name":"xyz",
    "age":"10",
    "gender":"female"
}

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I added @ComponentScan and then it worked. But my package structure  of my Application class is com.xyz.main and my controller class is com.xyz.controller. Why  it requires  explicit declaration here?

Any pointers? As per spring documentation  @SPringBootApplication does a scan across its package and all its subpackages right?

Comment: if you move the Application to `com.xyz` then the `com.xyz.controller` should be picked up automatically. The `@ComponentScan` works from the current directory. So in your case, only what it finds in `com.xyz.main` downwards.